# mongodb $not _id

Tags: mongodb, find, notin

I need a way to search but not include an _id which is already on the screen in front of the user. For example, I have 3 pet profiles one which the user is already viewing.

On that page I have a heading called My Family. I then run this search:

```
public function fetch_family($owner)
    {
        $collection = static::db()->mypet;
        $cursor = $collection->find(array('owner' => new MongoId($owner)));

        if ($cursor->count() > 0)
            {
                $family = array();
                // iterate through the results
                while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                    $family[] = ($cursor->getNext());
                }
                return $family;
            }
    }
```

And it returns all the pets in my family even knowing I am already showing one. So I want to exclude that one _id from the search.

I thought something like this.

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('owner' => new MongoId($owner), '$not'=>array('_id'=>new MongoId(INSERT ID HERE))));
```

However, that just stops the whole thing from running.

Comment: This is a good question, and I needed this info too, but you might consider doing this on the client side to save the server from the (very small) load of considering the object _id?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to do a [`$ne` (not equal)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/) to make sure the current pet you are viewing is excluded from the search by owner.

Example in the `mongo` shell:

```
var viewingPetId = ObjectId("515535b6760fe8735f5f6899");
var ownerId = ObjectId("515535ba760fe8735f5f689a");

db.mypet.find(
    {
        _id: { $ne: viewingPetId },
        owner: ownerId
    }
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `$ne` as (notice no need to use `ObjectId()`, string will autocast to `ObjectId`):

```
db.organizations.find({"_id" : {$ne:"563c50e05cdb2be30391e873"}})
```

Comment: Thus is just the same as what the provided answer says, so there is no need to add another one. Also as long as the schema type is present ( and always is for `_id` ) then mongoose will autocast from string anyway, which means an explicit conversion is not required.

Comment: I added it because I was getting "ObjectId not resolved error". What do you mean by autocast? do you mean db.organizations.find({"_id" : {$ne:"563c50e05cdb2be30391e873"}}) is sufficient?

Comment: Yes. Mongoose will take that string and convert it to an `ObjectId` automatically. You can see how it does this and the query sent to the server by enabling debugging. `mongoose.set('debug',true)`

Comment: Thanks, thats the right suggestion, answer updated as per your suggestion.

Comment: how about using $nin with array of string?